# How do i check the detail of cloud credits consumption

Tags: autodesk-forge

How do i check the detail of cloud credits consumption and whether there is some delay about declining the cloud credits

Answer (score 0):

You can use premium reporting API: https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/insights/v1/developers_guide/overview/